# Why I can't connect to an new H2 In-Memory database after closing?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring, h2

I use Spring 5.1.17, H2 (In Memory) Database 1.4.200 and Hibernate.

I use the H2 in-memory database for my test and I try to reset it after each test. For that, I create my database with Liquibase and generate a .sql-file. So my plan is, that after each test, I initialize a new in-memory DB by executing this .sql-file. For this, I don't want to drop all tables (because of time).
I only want to close the database and create a new in-memory DB which I can init by executing the sql-file (before each test). For this, I need to close the DB by executing the SQL statement `SHUTDOWN`. Then I get the following logs:

```
2021-02-12 12:59:57 database: disconnecting session #14
2021-02-12 12:59:57 database: disconnected session #14
2021-02-12 12:59:57 database: disconnecting session #3
2021-02-12 12:59:57 database: disconnected session #3
...
2021-02-12 12:59:57 database: disconnecting session #15
2021-02-12 12:59:57 database: closing mem:test
2021-02-12 12:59:57 database: closed
2021-02-12 12:59:57 database: disconnected session #15
```

Looks fine. Now I try to get connection to the (new) in-Memory DB with the same url:

```
...
String url = jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MSSQLServer;INIT=runscript from 'myPath/initFile.sql';DB_CLOSE_DELAY=0";
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
```

But this doesn't work!
It only works when I haven't shut down the DB before. So, when I run my spring application (with dataSource bean) and initialize the DB with the sql-file instead of Liquibase changelogs, I get the following logs and my tests will pass correctly:

```
/*SQL #:104 t:152*/runscript from 'myPath/initFile.sql';
2021-02-12 13:07:42 command: slow query: 152 ms
/**/Connection conn6 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=runscript from 'myPath/initFile.sql';MODE=MSSQLServer;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=0", "username", "");
```

But when I first run a test, shutdown the DB and try to connect&init the new DB, I dont get any log and the next tests will all fail because there are no tables. So it seems that no new DB will be created. Whats my mistake? Or is this not possible what I try to do?

Comment: I figured out that when I wait 300ms between shutting down and initializing again, it works. So the problem was that I re-created it too fast. But this is more a workaround and no good solution. I did not found a good solution for that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Quick read through [documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases) reveals following:

> By default, closing the last connection to a database closes the
> database. For an in-memory database, this means the content is lost.
> To keep the database open, add ;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 to the database URL.
> To keep the content of an in-memory database as long as the virtual
> machine is alive, use jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1.

As you explicitly configured `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=0` this seems to the case.

Try to set it to `-1`, something like this should do trick : `jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MSSQLServer;INIT=runscript from 'myPath/initFile.sql';DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1`

Comment: This doesn't work for my plan, because I want to setup a completly new Database. When I set the value to -1, I must drop all tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add to

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

in application.properties file.